# Passing Props From Parent To Child After Axios and UseEffect Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

Struggling with passing a prop to a child component after a UseEffect and Axios call. This is my main call at the start of my `StandingsComponent`:

```
export const StandingsComponent = () => {
    const [payload, setPayload] = useState([]);

    const classes = useStyles();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(
                '$URL',
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'x-api-key': '$api-key'
                    }
                }
            )
            .then(function (response) {
                setPayload(response.data.teams);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);

    const groupA = payload.filter((team) => team.groupName === 1);
    const groupB = payload.filter((team) => team.groupName === 2);

    return (
        <Column>
            <Row>
                <GroupComponent
                    teams={groupA}
                />
                <GroupComponent
                    teams={groupB} />
            </Row>
        </Column>
    );
};
```

The `console.log()` for both groups are fine:

```
[{id: 5, name: "Italy", groupName: 1},
{id: 18, name: "Switzerland", groupName: 1},
{id: 21, name: "Turkey", groupName: 1},
{id: 22, name: "Wales", groupName: 1}]
```

```
[{id: 4, name: "Russia", groupName: 2},
{id: 6, name: "Denmark", groupName: 2},
{id: 13, name: "Belgium", groupName: 2},
{id: 25, name: "Finland", groupName: 2}]
```

But when I get to `GroupComponent`, I'm not able to `console.log()` the values from the `teams` prop. I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

```
export const GroupComponent = ({teams }) => {
    const theme = useTheme();
    const classes = useStyles({ theme });

    function renderStat(title, value) {
        return (
            <Row horizontal='space-between' vertical='center'>
                <span className={classes.itemTitle}>{title}</span>
                <span className={[classes.itemTitle, classes.itemValue].join(' ')}>{value}</span>
            </Row>
        );
    }

    console.log(teams[0].name); //TypeError here

    return (
        <CardComponent
            items={[
                renderStat(teams[0].name, teams[0].id),
                renderStat(teams[1].name, teams[1].id),
                renderStat(teams[2].name, teams[2].id),
                renderStat(teams[3].name, teams[3].id1)
            ]}
        ></CardComponent>
    );
};

export default GroupComponent;
```

I'm still getting my head around objects in JavaScript and async calls with the axios API. How do I pass the `teams` prop in to the `GroupComponent` and avoid the `undefined` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only show the `GroupComponent` when proper array is fetched.

```js
return (
    <Column>
        <Row>
            {
                groupA.length !== 0 && <GroupComponent teams={groupA} />
            }
            {
                groupB.length !== 0 && <GroupComponent teams={groupB} />
            }
        </Row>
    </Column>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `async` and `await` to wait result fetching from url.

```
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const loadData = async () => {
        const response = await Axios.get(url);
        setPayload(response.data.teams);
      };
      loadData();
    },
    []
  );
```

In `GroupComponent`, then you should check if `teams` is unloaded to notify loading...

```
  if (!teams || !teams.length) {
    return <div>Loading data ...</div>;
  }
```

Once `teams` has been set, `GroupComponent` update automatically.

Comment: where does the if statement go in the `GroupComponent` ? I'm struggling to get it to show

Comment: you should place if statement before return (`console.log` will not work and should be removed in your code) of `GroupComponent` to check it is able to render `CardComponent`